# Python multiprocess seems not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am learning Python multiprocessing, this is my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time 

def cube(list_i, result_i):
    for i in list_i:
        result_i[i]=i**3
    return
def test():
    result_i=list(range(10000000))
    list_i=list(range(10000000))
    single=mp.Process(target=cube, args=(range(10000000),result_i))
    t=time.time()
    single.start()
    single.join()
    print(time.time()-t)
    multiple=[mp.Process(target=cube, args=(i, result_i)) for i in [range(i*2500000, i*2500000+2500000) for i in range(4)]]
    t=time.time()
    for process in multiple:
        process.start()
    for process in multiple:
        process.join()
    print(time.time()-t)
    return

if __name__=='__main__':
    test()
```

## output:

```
12.0096
32.0467
```

It seems that single process is faster? My computer's cpu is i5-5200 with 4 cores.

Comment: There are overheads associated with launching new processes. In your case these overheads could be more time consuming than running the actual calculations! Do you get the same discrepancy with much larger numbers?

Comment: I modified my questions. It still seems not working though @101

Comment: Can you show us the `cube` function?

Comment: @101 now it is complete. thanks!

Comment: @Rickyim could you explain what is `list_i` variable? As I see, it do not use.

Comment: Compute the cube of the elements in list_i and save them in results_i. Could the problem be the share of results_i among different sub_process? @DanilaGanchar

Comment: @Rickyim yes. because you sent list

Comment: @Rickyim if you need to share data you must need to use [value, array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Note! when doing concurrent programming it is usually best to avoid using shared state as far as possible

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I'll test out if that was the cause of the slow down

Comment: @Rickyim just read about [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). share objects between processes is harder

Comment: I tried without sharing again. single process still faster. Is it possible that you try and show what kind of code should work? You can post in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with [Manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

import requests


# for example we will fetch data about countries
def call_url(url: str, result: dict):
    response = requests.get(url)

    result['data'] = response.json()


def test():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    # result of process
    result = manager.dict()
    # send url and result to process
    single = mp.Process(
        target=call_url,
        args=(
            'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all',
            result,
        ))
    start_time = time.time()
    single.start()
    # wait when process is finish and print time + result
    single.join()
    print('\nSingle time: %s' % (time.time() - start_time))
    print('\nSingle result: %s' % result.values())

    processes = []
    start_time = time.time()
    # create 4 processes and fetch data in each process
    for i in range(4):
        result = manager.dict()
        process = mp.Process(
            target=call_url,
            args=(
                'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all',
                result,
            ))
        processes.append((process, result, ))
        process.start()
    # wait until all processes are finished
    for process, _ in processes:
        process.join()
    # print results of each process and time
    print('\nresults: ')
    for _, result in processes:
        print('\n')
        print(result.values())

    print('\n4 process time: %s' % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Run our script(`Python 3.6.1`). Example of output:

```
Single time: 0.9279030323028564

Single result: [[{'name': 'Afghanistan'...

results: # long output (the same result as in single - [[{'name': 'Afghanistan'...)

4 process time: 1.0175669193267822

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, as you can see 0.9 ~= 1.0. But in the second time was sent 4 requests. Also you can use [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), [Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) etc. There are many examples on SO(also in internet).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the problem lies in the larger overhead of multiprocesses, as pointed out earlier.